# Java / Nashorn put one function in binding / global scope

Tags: java, scope, nashorn

I have one static method like:

```
some abstract class C {
    void dump( Object o ) {
}
```

which I'd like to pass to js that I can use it directly in the global scope like:

```
js> dump( new Something() );
```

So far the only way I found is creating an instance like

```
public class CStub {
    void dump( Object o ){ C.dump( o ); }
}
```

putting it in nashorn via:

```
engine.put( "stub", new CStub() );
```

and then in js:

```
js> var dump = stub.dump
```

but is there another approach to this which doesn't involve the stub creation and puts the method directly in the global scope?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can implement a functional interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) like java.util.function.Function in your class and expose an object of it as a global variable to nashorn. Nashorn treats any "functional interface" object as a function and allows direct call to it.
Simple example that exposes a "dump" function is as follows:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
   // a Function implementation
   private static class MyFunc implements Function<String, Void> {
       @Override
       public Void apply(String msg) {
           System.out.println(msg);
           return null;
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
       ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

       // expose functional interface object as a global var
       e.put("dump", new MyFunc());

       // invoke functional interface object like a function!
       e.eval("dump('hello')");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! It works. With some strangeness, though.

Answer (score 4):

Even shorter, you can take a method reference (`C::dump`), cast it to an appropriate functional interface (in your case `Consumer` is fine as it receives a single argument and returns void), and put it into global scope

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // expose method-reference-as-function-object as a global var
        e.put("dump", (Consumer<Object>)C::dump);

        // invoke functional interface object like a function!
        e.eval("dump('hello')");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the end. Unexpectedly the method signature from the java side was a little different then when using an instance.